# VB.NET Code is generating a value of 0, but I cant see how that is possible

Tags: vb.net, file, loops

The code below is meant to generate an ID number when a client record is added to the file. But the ID number that it generates is always coming out as 0. why is this?

```
For index = 1 To LOF(1) / Len(ClientRecord) 
            FileGet(1, ClientRecord, index)
            If ClientRecord.ClientID > IDofClientRecord Then
                IDofClientRecord = ClientRecord.ClientID
            End If
            IDofClientRecord = IDofClientRecord + 1
            IDofClientRecord = ClientRecord.ClientID
        Next
```

Comment: It is sooooo much easier to store records in a database or serialize a collection of them than use those legacy VB functions

Comment: Sadly I have to do it this way for my course.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot you don't specify here, but lets take a stab at it.
If the ID you are trying to generate is ClientRecord.ClientID, then I think this is your problem:

IDofClientRecord = IDofClientRecord + 1

IDofClientRecord = ClientRecord.ClientID

The second line overrides the first line and you never make any progress.
If you reverse the second to last line to:

ClientRecord.ClientID = IDofClientRecord

it may work, but that assumes information not in the record ;-)

Comment: While this _should_ ensure strictly increasing `ClientRecord.ClientID`s, it _seems_ to increment `ClientRecord.ClientID` even if it started out (was gotten from file) greater than `IDofClientRecord`.

Comment: I tried this but it did something very strange. It made the clientID increment by a bigger number each time. It went from 1 to 2 to 4 to 7 to 11 to 16 and so on. I cannot figure it out

Comment: yeah, there is something wrong with the logic, but I can't tell what you are trying to do.  Can you better explain what that code is trying to do?